# div width the same as its first element

Tags: css

I have multiple divs side by side. Each div contains an image, followed by the title of that image under the image. How can I make the width of the div the same as the width of an image, so the text under the image doesn't stretch the div?

Comment: Without adding relevant code to your question, will closed by the moderators automatically. if you really want answers then post the code what you have tried and then explain what is the problem.

Comment: Not sure this is possible without JavaScript to fix the width of the div to be the same as the image.

Comment: Need more information to be helpful. Trying adding a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`min-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) for a width.

```css
div {
  margin:1em;
  border:1px solid;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="">
  An image.
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="">
  Another image.
</div>
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for. But unfortunately it is not well supported. I'm gonna go solve it using jQuery. Thanks for your help.